# Pandas memory leak when setting last row value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory-leaks

I ran this code with debugger row by row while monitoring the process memory, and i noticed that memory is growing by just overriding the last value of some column in last row.
using gc.collect was not helping

```
import pandas as pd
import gc
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [[1.0, 1.1, 1.2], [2.0, 2.1, 2.2], [3.0, 3.1, 3.2]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', "Col3"])
    print(df)
    print(f'rows: {df.shape[0]}, cols: {df.shape[1]}')
    print(df.memory_usage())
    print(df.info())

    df.loc[df.index[-1], "Col1"] = 1.0
    df.loc[df.index[-1], "Col2"] = 2.0
    df.loc[df.index[-1], "Col3"] = 3.0
    df.loc[df.index[-1], "Col1"] = 4.0
    df.loc[df.index[-1], "Col1"] = 5.0
    df.loc[df.index[-1], "Col2"] = 1.0
    df.loc[df.index[-1], "Col3"] = 2.0
    df.loc[df.index[-1], "Col3"] = 3.0
    df.loc[df.index[-1], "Col3"] = 4.0
    df.loc[df.index[-1], "Col2"] = 5.0
    print(df.memory_usage())
    print(df.info())
    gc.collect()
    print(df.memory_usage())
    print(df.info())
```

tried also to use:

```
df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('Col1')] = 1.0
```

but same results.

memory consumption for this dataframe is 200 bytes in all prints.
so why my process memory is increasing?

thanks :)